# Sample Open Child Window with Design Time support

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am learning WPF with M-V-VM pattern. I make Progress and learning a lot.

Question: I there a sample opening a Child Window with Design Time Data presented in VS?

So the Content binding need to be in the in the xaml i assume, but how can I open the child window and pass a property over the child (Observable List)? The list should show in VS with desin data (Showing design data works in VS). A simple sample is most wanted.

I use the MVVM Light Toolkit (GalaSoft) as a helping Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get VS to open a child window from the IDE. However you can get VS to show you the child window as it will appear with data inside its design time IDE.

You will need to create a window using the normal controls, and in the xaml add

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   ...
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
   d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModel:YourViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" >
```

This will cause VS to create an instance of `YourViewModel` and bind all your values to it at design time. VS2012 or Resharper will also give you intellisense in your Bindings.